# export all warnings in file in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, shell

I have written script that shows Xcode warnings. e.g `TODO` warnings. This script will run on each build of XCode. (I have written script in "Run Phase" option).

Now I want to collect and export all these warnings to text files. Is there any way to export all warnings or build errors to a text file?

Comment: Sounds useful, would you be willing to share your script as a Gist?

Comment: Sure I will...By using this suppose I putted "TODO comments" in my source code. e.g. // TODO: Need to refactor later. We can covert these all in Xcode warnings and these warnings can be exported in text file, which will be beneficial for documentation.

Comment: I use TODO, and then search for them in the project as part of my workflow, having them be more in my face would be nice. I'm not so worried about a separate file personally, but having them in the warnings would be good!

Comment: But I am not thinking about only TODO...suppose you are doing code review so you can put tag like "//Review by Ian"..then you can export it!! Obviously, it will be beneficial to developer if it is in-front of him...

Comment: Definitely. Not trying to suggest what you're asking isn't good. I can see good applications for it. I'm keen to see if anyone answers. All I was saying is that I'd find even what you already have quite useful!

Comment: Thanks for appreciating it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(the first bit of this is what you've already done, or something like it)

## Outputting TODO, etc, as warnings.

Select your project, click the Build Phases tab, and select 'Add Build Phase > Add Run Script Build Phase' from the 'Editor' menu.

In the script box use a script something like this:

```
KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

(courtesy of: http://deallocatedobjects.com/posts/show-todos-and-fixmes-as-warnings-in-xcode-4)

The `KEYWORDS` regular expression matches `TODO:`, `FIXME:`, `???:` and `!!!:`, but could be adjusted to find whichever indicators you want.

## Making this output to a file.

The script currently outputs to `stdout`, which is picked up by XCode and parsed. To make it also log to a file, use `tee` as part of the script (see the end of line 2 for the change):

```
KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/" | tee "${SRCROOT}/NOTICES.txt"
```

This approach can be as complex as you like, of course, as well as `tee`ing to a file, we can augment the script to do anything we choose:

```
KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/" | tee ${SRCROOT}/NOTICES.txt
mail -s NOTICES idmillington@example.com < ${SRCROOT}/NOTICES.txt
```

That emails it to me.

I've confirmed this works with XCode 5.0.2, including emailing.

---

Note that this does not export all warnings from the build to a file, which is strictly what you asked. I can't find a way to automate this in XCode 5.0.2, though you can do it with `xcodebuild`. From within the UI, the only option is to copy the log text from the log navigator to the clipboard, it seems.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian...I guess that is enough to track review comments/ todo comments in documentation...Sending it to email also may beneficial..let me know if u find anything feature that we need to add in this  to automate...