# How to export all warnings in Xcode to a file?

Tags: xcode, terminal

Is there any way to export all warnings that are appearing in Xcode to an external file? Are there any terminal commands that can achieve that. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047112/export-all-warnings-in-file-in-xcode) question but it does not address warnings like:

> Variable 'sacKey' was written to, but never read

Any help would be greatly appreciated.